# How to prevent a wrapper object wrapping itself?

Tags: python, new-operator

```
class A():
    ...
```

I want class `A` that is initialized with any object as parameter, but when `__init__` goes with `A` type, it should leave/return old `A` object, dont create wrapper `A(A())`.

I guess that overwrite `__new__` method is solution, but how there stop creating `object creator` and return given parameter as a result.

My workaround now is just recommendation:

```
def ToA(it):
    if type(it) == A:
        return it
    else: 
        return A(it)
```

But I need block somehow `A` to prevent direct use of `A(A())`.

Comment: This looks like a decorator.

Comment: I think your only two options are the ones you mention: `__new__` in the class, or a conversion method. Probably `__new__` makes the most sense depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not at all sure I understand what you want, but something like this *may* be it.  You can't have an `__init__` with this technique, because if you do, it will be called *regardless* of whether `__new__` returned a new object.

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, cls):
            return obj
        rv = object.__new__(cls)

        # everything you would normally put in __init__
        # goes here instead
        rv._obj = obj
        return rv

    # for instance:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A({})".format(repr(self._obj))
```

---

```
>>> A()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
>>> A(1)
A(1)
>>> A(A(1))
A(1)
```

---

Not being able to use `__init__` is troublesome, particularly if you need to subclass `A`.   Here's a way to work around that:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, cls):
            return obj
        rv = object.__new__(cls)
        rv._initialized = False
        return rv

    def __init__(self, obj):
        if self._initialized: return
        self._obj = obj
        self._initialized = True

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        if self._initialized: return
        A.__init__(self, obj)
        self._otherthing = "foo"
```

You have to check `self._initialized` in every subclass's `__init__` method, unfortunately.

Comment: nice trick, I was fighting with ``__new__`` used only to checking type, then rest was in ``__init__`` - my mistake.

Comment: It occurs to me now that you should use `isinstance(obj, cls)` instead of `type(obj) is cls` -- the latter will not work correctly if `A` is ever subclassed.

Comment: understood. I must remeber to not add ``__init__`` in any of subclass - a bit problematic.

Comment: I edited the answer with a workaround that lets you use `__init__`.  You have to remember to add some boilerplate in each subclass's `__init__`, but at least it will work.